# Run package tests for Meteor

Tags: meteor

I want to write a PR which updates Underscore JS to version 1.8 and I try to run the existing test suite to get a pass before I update the code, but get the following..

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
9fbea207d350334499e4218ff82c5928aa8dd0a9 #meteor/meteor/devel
$ meteor test-packages packages/underscore
[[[[[ Tests ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While selecting package versions:
   error: No version of underscore satisfies all constraints: @=1.0.4-plugins.0, @=1.0.3
```

I get this for `tracker` package as well, same error, different number.
Get similar error on `METEOR@1.0.2-rc.7` as well - is there a different way to test than what I'm using ?

Comment: It was a good suggestion though, thanks!

Comment: There is one small issue with your question. According to that answer, it was because you are using the release candidate. The only way we can know is by looking at the version you tried to use, maybe you should make it more clear you were using the RC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was due to my playing with the current release candidate; I needed to pass a `--release` flag

```
meteor --release METEOR@1.0.2-rc.7 test-packages ./
```

[This post](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3536) let me know that I needed to do:

Comment: You may want to add more details relative to this post.